# how to replace a column value which is separated by comma in SQL

Tags: sql

I am having a table which is having a column named as CDR.
In that CDR column we have values stored as comma separated like 20,5,40,10,30
I just need to replace last value(here it is 30) to 0 in every row.
Can someone suggest me how can we do?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using MsSQL server?

Comment: Never, ever store data as comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: what database are you using?

Comment: You can do it with code.

Comment: You'll get more accurate answers if you update the tags to include which RDMS you are using.

Comment: It is there since long. So nothing can be done until we completely move.. need to manage somehow..

Answer (score 1):

If you are able, first correct the database design as the table is not in first normal form.  It is bad design to have more than one value stored in one column, as evidenced by you having to ask this question.  :-)  Having said that, I have to deal with vendor data that has the same issue that is beyond my control to change, so in Oracle 11g I would do this:

```
update table_name
set CDR = regexp_replace(CDR, '(.*,)\d+$', '\10');
```

The regex matches and remembers all characters up to and including the last comma before one or more digits right before the end of the string.  The replace string is the remembered part referenced by the \1, referring to the first grouping of characters inside parenthesis), plus the 0.

Comment: what is \10 stands here?

Comment: See the last sentence.  A reference to the first remembered group (\1) which is the entire string except the last element in the list, concatenated with the '0'.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server, this should do for you.

```
create table #A(id int , cdr varchar(100))

insert into #A values(1,'10,20,30,40'),(2, '20,30,40,50'),(3,'30,40,50,60,70')

Declare @tA as table(id int , String varchar(10))
insert into @tA
SELECT  id,
   Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS String  
FROM  (SELECT [id],  
       CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE([cdr], ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS String  
   FROM  #A) AS A CROSS APPLY String.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a);

   delete from @tA where [String] = '30'


   SELECT distinct id,
ISNULL(STUFF((SELECT ', ' + String
FROM @tA t
WHERE t.id = ta.id
FOR XML PATH('')
), 1, 1, ''), '') AS Str
into #tempA
FROM @tA ta

   select * from #tempA

   drop table #A, #tempA
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE TableName
   SET CDR = REPLACE(CDR, (SUBSTRING( CDR, LEN(CDR) -  CHARINDEX(',',REVERSE(CDR)) + 2  , LEN(CDR))),0);
```

[image]

Comment: sorry it didnt work for me because of CHARINDEX is not compatible in SQL

Comment: this answer is for MSSQL Server. The CHARINDEX function can be used in the following versions of  SQL Server 2014, SQL Server 2012, SQL Server 2008 R2, SQL Server 2008, SQL Server 2005

Answer (score 0):

You should think about splitting up your comma separated list into a separate table. That way you can do other things in SQL. SQL is not the best with string manipulation and your queries are gonna get obscene and unruly.

```
table Users
user_id      user_name      job_list
1            Billy          "1,2,3,4"

table Jobs
job_id       job_desc
1            plumber
2            carpenter
3            electrician
4            programmer
```

If you do this you're gonna have some heartaches where a job goes away or something you're gonna have a lot of annoying cleanup like @jarlh suggests.

If you make a third table to hold the relationships `user_id` to `job_id` you will have a much better time if you need to do something like delete a `job_id` from existence. Of course this is all made up based on your limited question, but it should help you out.

```
table UserJobRelationship
relationship_id     user_id       job_id
1                   1             1
2                   1             2
3                   1             3
4                   1             4
```

Gives you much more flexibility and allows you to delete the most recent entry. You can simply just do `max` of `relationship_id` where `user_id` equals that user or you can do it for the whole table.